# Fill geom_tile by mode of a factor variable or other ways to create a heat map in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I am trying to create a heat map in R using three factors. I would like to be able to fill the colour using the modal category of one of the factors but I have not been able to find out how to do this.

When I try ggplot with geom_tile, it does produce the heatmap, however, I am not sure how it chooses the value of the fill variable. It certainly isn't the mode because I've checked this.

For instance, using the inbuilt dataset ChickWeight, I would like the fill to be based on the modal (most frequent) category of a variable "weight_group" I created.

```r
data(ChickWeight)
glimpse(ChickWeight)
    
ChickWeight$Time <- ifelse(ChickWeight$Time >= 10,1,0)
ChickWeight <- ChickWeight %>% mutate(weight_group = ntile(weight, 3))
    
ChickWeight$Diet <- as.factor(ChickWeight$Diet)
ChickWeight$Time <- as.factor(ChickWeight$Time)
ChickWeight$weight_group <- as.factor(ChickWeight$weight_group)
    
    
table(ChickWeight$Diet, ChickWeight$Time, ChickWeight$weight_group)
    
ggplot(data = ChickWeight, aes(x=Time, y=Diet, fill=weight_group)) + 
  geom_tile()
```

[image: Result of ggplot]

Based on the three-way table, the bottom right block should be pink (corresponding to weight_group==1) rather than green as the modal category of weight_group when Diet==1 & Time==1 is weight_group==1 (11 counts).

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a function getMode that calculates the mode of a vector using plyr's count function to create a data frame of the counts for each class. Then sort the data frame and get the top value.

```
library(plyr)
getMode <- function(vec){
  df <- plyr::count(vec) %>%
    arrange(-freq)
  return(df[1,"x"])
}
```

From here group by time and diet so you can find the mode for each combination of these groups and then use this as the fill for ggplot.

```
ChickWeight %>%
  group_by(Time, Diet) %>%
  summarize(modeWeightGroup = getMode(weight_group)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Time, y=Diet, fill= modeWeightGroup)) + 
  geom_tile()
```

I also don't think that the bottom right square should be weight_group 1 because it looks like the three way table is already sorted based on weight_group so that square is saying that of chicks in weight_group 1, their modal time, diet combination is (1,1).

Comment: I meant the "should" as a desired result. Will be clearer next time.

Comment: @Maria the graph show shows the modal category given and combination of Time and Diet, but the three-way table shows the break down of Time, Date pairs given a weight_group value, so they won't line up. Are you trying to make the graph based on the table or fix the existing graph?

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` to count the most frequent category of `weight_group` for each combination of `Time` and `Diet` :

```
ChickWeight %>% 
  group_by(Time, Diet) %>% 
  count(weight_group) %>% 
  filter(n == max(n)) %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(x = Time,
        y = Diet,
        fill = weight_group)
    ) + 
  geom_tile()
```

By the way, since you already know `dplyr::mutate`, you should know you can do all the pre-processing you are doing here inside a single mutate.
That means instead of :

```
ChickWeight$Time <- ifelse(ChickWeight$Time >= 10,1,0)
ChickWeight <- ChickWeight %>% mutate(weight_group = ntile(weight, 3))

ChickWeight$Diet <- as.factor(ChickWeight$Diet)
ChickWeight$Time <- as.factor(ChickWeight$Time)
ChickWeight$weight_group <- as.factor(ChickWeight$weight_group)
```

you can simply type :

```
ChickWeight <- 
  ChickWeight %>% 
  mutate(
    Time = as.factor(ifelse(Time>=10, 1 ,0)),
    Diet = as.factor(Diet),
    weight_group = as.factor(ntile(weight, 3))
  )
```